# python re with groupdict

Tags: python

I'm writing a python code to slipt all informations from a .txt. And i have write a code, but come allways error:  *'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'*

code:

```
import re
readfile = open("test.txt")
try:
all_the_text =readfile.read()
m = re.match("(pdflink=[\w\s/]*)author=([\w\s/]*/n)",unicode(all_the_text),flags=re.UNICODE)
m.groupdict()
print m.groupdict()
finally:
readfile.close()
writefile = open('test5.txt','w')
print >> writefile, m.groupdict()
writefile.close()
```

Please please help me! Thx!

Comment: It means your `re.match` never matches anything... Are you sure you shouldn't be using `re.search` ? [it might help to show some sample input data...]

Comment: match method, returns None type if the string does not match the pattern, as said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Python documentation:

`re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)¶
If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this is different from a zero-length match`

In your code, re.match is returning None and storing that in `m`. So `m` is `None`. You then try to call `groupdict` from `m`, and you get the aformentioned error. So you should first check to see if `m` is `None` before continuing your processing.

Comment: Thx! Though i change to re.reasch, it doesn't work...or the groupdict function can just built with match function?